# In Windows Task Manager, in the Processes tab, what does I/O Other mean?

Tags: windows-server-2003, process, io, task-manager

In Windows Server 2003, I'm seeing a process in Task Manager with a high value in the I/O Other column. I'm trying to determine if it's in some kind of error state, but I don't know what I/O Other means. I/O Reads and Writes are low. What is I/O Other?

I'm also looking for any more detail I can get on what an I/O Other operation is, more explanation than "An example of this type of operation is a control function." Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958260.aspx):

> The number of input/output operations generated by a process that are
>   neither reads nor writes, including file, network, and device I/Os. An
>   example of this type of operation would be a control function. I/O
>   Others directed to CONSOLE (console input object) handles are not
>   counted.

If you need more detailed info than Task Manager provides, take a look at Process Explorer and Process Monitor from Sysinternals.

Answer (score 1):

See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-do-the-Task-Manager-memory-columns-mean

Quote:  "The number of input/output operations generated by the process that are neither a read nor a write, including file, network, and device I/Os. An example of this type of operation is a control function. I/O Other operations directed to CONSOLE (console input object) handles are not counted."

Comment: Though the link specifies Windows Vista, the same description also applies to 2K3 Server.